# Dropdown menu in html table

Tags: html, button, drop-down-menu, html-table

The dropdown menu is not shown when I click on the button; the menu is covered by the HTML table's row.

See the attached picture. The menu is in highlighted in yellow.

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please, add any relevent code to your question. We simply **can not** help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `z-index`...

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Also keep in mind that the element has to have `position: absolute` or `position: relative` applied!

Comment: The problem was that that <td> was given overflow:hidden property.